# Loop in Java until the user presses any key (not just the Enter key) in a console app

Tags: java

I know it is possible to loop until the user presses the enter key:

```
while (system.in.available() == 0) {
  // ...
}
```

But I don't know how to loop until the user presses any key:

```
while (any_key_is_not_pressed) {
  // ...
}
```

I know that there is a way to do it in a GUI by tracking keyboard events. Can I do it in a console app?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think so.  Getting into the details of drivers for consoles is a big, big headache.  Java seems to have obviated this problem by only allowing line input, not individual characters.  (If you need to input a password, there's a `Console.readPassword()` method that echoes stars instead of the character a user types.)

Comment: Interestingly enough, the correct answer is the **second** on the duplicated answer: you can't do what you want! The console does not report back individual chars, only after enter is pressed you get to see it!